# Filtering ckeditor content when being retrieved from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, html, asp.net-mvc-4

First off I realize there is similar questions like this out there, however I am a newbie and none seem to answer specifically what I'm trying achieve.
I am building an asp.net MVC 4 application, basically I have the content of the ckeditor textbox (entered by the user) saving to the database.
The problem being when I retrieve the data it has tags like the following attached....

<p>ck editor test 2</p>

instead of

ck editor test 2

Is there a clean way of returning the data to be displayed without the tags , but still display bold text for example.

ps - I am not using Web-forms (as many similar solutions involve)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little help,

@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(item.Body))

in place of

@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Body)

thats all it took.